# Jest: Cannot read property of undefined when importing from own package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have created a package named `@package/test`. When imported to a new, empty React typescript app works perfectly. Problems start in Jest tests suites.

The `commonJS` package version cause Jest to throw:

`Test suite failed to run. TypeError:Cannot read property 'getSelectors' of undefined`

```js
import { Test } from `@package/test
const selectors = Test.getSelectors(...); //error here indicating that Test is undefined
```

When I compiled an `ES modules` package version, it causes Jest to throw

```
export * from './common';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

which is the first line of my `src/index.ts` inside my package.

I have tested many solutions e.g.:

- Defining `transformIgnorePatterns` for Jest
- Searching for circular dependencies using `eslint` plugins and `Madge`
- Tested on Node.js versions: 10.20.0, 12.21.0, 15.12.0
- Tested on typescript versions: 3.7.5, 4.1.2

**Some details about the package**:

```json
/* package.json */
{
  "name": "@package/test",
  "version": "2.4.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b ./tsconfig.package.json"
  },
  "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {...},
  "peerDependencies": {...},
  "sideEffects": "false"
}
```

```json
/* tsconfig.package.json */
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.packages.json",
  "compilerOptions": { "outDir": "./dist", "rootDir": "./src", "composite": true },
  "references": [],
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.*", "dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

```json
/* tsconfig.packages.json */
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015", "es2020", "dom"]
  }
}
```

```json
/* tsconfig.base.json */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

How `Test` is exported:

```js
import * as actions from './actions';
import reducer, { Action, RootState} from './reducer';
import getSelectors from './getSelectors';

export const Test = {
  actions,
  reducer,
  getSelectors,
};

export { Action, RootState};
export * from './types';
export * from './helpers';
```

How `getSelectors` is exported:

```js
export default function getSelectors<S>(selectNavigation: Selector<S, RootState>) {
  const getInitialized = createSelector(selectNavigation, (s) => s.initialized);
    ...
  return { getInitialized, ... };
}
```

**React test application details**

```json
/* package.json */
{
  "name": "jest-verify",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@package/test": "2.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
}
```

```json
/* tsconfig.json */
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

EDIT:
I managed to make it work in my test React app with `transformIgnorePatterns`, but unfortunately it does not work in my Angular 1.6 (webpack, babel) app. Added also some babel plugins to transform package into commonJS, but no effect.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was way more complex than it appeared.

#### Extra issue:

`Jest` was not respecting `Babel` config in `json` file. I had to transform it to `js`.

### Solution no. 1:

- Install `@babel/preset-env` as a dev dependency.
- Register it as a preset in Babel's config:

```js
env: {
    test: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
    },
}
```

- Register required `transformIgnorePatterns` in `Jest` config
- Add this to the `transform` section in `Jest` config: `"^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"`

### Solutions no. 2:

- Install `babel-jest` and `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` as dev dependencies.
- Register the plugin in Babel's config:

```js
env: {
    test: {
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
    },
}
```

- Register required `transformIgnorePatterns` in `Jest` config
- Add this to the `transform` section in `Jest` config: `"^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"`

Comment: Hi, any idea how this should work in a nextjs project, and there's no .babelrc file in nextjs project... thx!